# xpath OR operator for multiple values

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

For the following scenario, xpath OR operator is not working. The same label showing in different nodes in different pages.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "(//label[@class='x-form-item-label'])[19] | (//label[@class='x-form-item-label'])[36]")
public WebElement lblFee;
```

Comment: I don't see an "or" operator in your expression. I only see a "union" operator. Perhaps that's why you think it's not working - it's the wrong operator.

Comment: Are others attributes available or is there any way of identifying a unique parent for these labels? Can you provide some examples? Is this element displayed in a certain position? for example always last or something like that

Comment: as Michael Kay notes, that "|" character is not an "or".  You'll get a node set returned, and your code is attempting to return a single WebElement.  I think lauda is correct, you probably need to come up with a different approach.  your "Fee" label could appear in a couple of places.  why are you looking for the label, is that what you really need to find, or are you looking for a value, which would be a different path all together.  share some html source so that we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `position()` function with the `or` operator:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "(//label[@class='x-form-item-label'])[position()=19 or position()=36]")
public WebElement lblFee;
```